# Adding up int values in a column based on str in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code that will add up all of the "counts" in each state. Here is an example of my .dbf(csv) file.

```
Count        Lat                    Lon       index_righ  STATE
1345    31.551580000000000  -88.448380000000000 1992    Alabama
445     31.999867999999900  -88.404543000000000 1992    Alabama
299     32.448521000000000  -88.360196000000000 1992    Alabama
106     32.897511999999900  -88.315329000000000 1992    Alabama
229     33.346817000000000  -88.269934000000000 1992    Alabama
270     33.796408999999900  -88.224000000000000 1992    Alabama
217     34.246262999999900  -88.177518000000000 1992    Alabama
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Count    State
2911     Alabama
etc.     etc.
```

Here is my code.

```
result = {}
with open('C:/Users/brownk98/Desktop/result_out.dbf', 'rt') as f:
    count = 0
    #r = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in f:
        values = row.split(",")
        count = None
        state = None
        count = int(values[0])
        state = str(values[4])
        if state is not None:
            if state not in result :
                result[state] += count
            else:
                result[state] = count
print(result)
```

I receive the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x03u\x07\n'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is usually never wise to use an open exception -> `except Exception`. You will end up catching *everything* and suppress any errors you actually want to know about to indicate to you any odd behaviour that should not be happening. Furthermore, in order to help with your own troubleshooting if you don't have a debugger handy, is to use some print statements inside your code to see where you can catch exactly where the code is "misbehaving"

Comment: Can you show an example from the input file? In the example input you gave, the delimiter is not a comma and there are not five columns. Also, your `if state not in result` clause seems to be backwards.

Comment: I have edited my original question to include an example from the input file

Comment: It looks like your delimiter should be `\t`, not `,`.

Comment: What idjaw said... have your `except` clause print out the value of `values`, and you'll probably see why things aren't happening as expected.

Comment: When I print out my values, it appears to only be reading in the first three columns (even after changing my delimiter to \t). The last two are not included. How can I fix this?

Comment: Step 1 is understanding what the format of the data file actually is. It doesn't sound like it's a simple CSV/TSV.

Comment: Its a .dbf file in a csv format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kayla, you are all correct. Unsure of why its throwing you an error. Here is what I tried and it worked. Please note I've prepared a **".csv"** file with your input

```
result= {}
with open('trail.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        count, state = int(row[0]), row[4]
        if state in result.keys():
            result[state] += count
        else:
            result[state] = count
    print( result )  


>> {'Alabama': 2911}
```

Considering your case, in case the file is huge and you are unable to convert it to .CSV, try to split using tab i.e., `values = row.split("\t")`

Comment: This gave me the error "Error: line contains NULL bye"   for the line "for row in reader:"  Thank you for your help though, I appreciate the support.

Comment: I converted my .dbf file into a .csv and this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @KaylaBrown please make sure you accept the answer that helped resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

try using pandas groupby builtin function.

My csv look likes that

```
Count Lat Lon index_righ STATE
1345 31.551580000000000 -88.448380000000000 1992 Alabama
445 31.999867999999900 -88.404543000000000 1992 Alabama
299 32.448521000000000 -88.360196000000000 1992 Alabama
106 32.897511999999900 -88.315329000000000 1992 Alabama
229 33.346817000000000 -88.269934000000000 1992 Alabama
270 33.796408999999900 -88.224000000000000 1992 Alabama
217 34.246262999999900 -88.177518000000000 1992 Alabama
```

in python :

```
data=pd.read_csv('datatest.csv',sep=' ')
data.groupby(['STATE']).sum().drop(['Lat','Lon','index_righ'],axis = 1)
```

output

```
         Count
STATE         
Alabama   2911
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it seems promising. However, I received the error: "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 4566355" I am not sure what this means.

Comment: I think your csv file is poorly edited. If your first line was like mine it should have wrote you : expected 5 fields ... (instead of 1). You have to be coherent in your csv file either put separator between columns as one space or a semicolon. Also, please do the edit directly on the csv file and do not open it as an excel file. Most of parser error occur because excel file are improperly closed ...